# Destructure in TS

Tags: typescript

Working through trying to learn TypeScript and I have a quick question about destructing something.  Say I have an object. I need to destruct prior to using the variables.  For instance:

```
type artProps = {
    articles: Article[],
    loading: boolean
}
type Article = {
    title: string,
    author: string,
    body: string,
    date: number,
    category: string,
    _id: string
}

const [articles, loading] = data
```

How would I destructure data while declaring the type?

Comment: Why do you destructure an object as an array? `const { articles, loading } = data` should work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the standard `: type` notation.

## Example without destructuring

```
const foo:[number,string]  = data;
```

## Example *with* destructuring

```
const [articles, loading]:[number,string] = data;
```